# Changing ubuntu logo when load booting

Tags: 14.04, boot, logo

I'm under Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried to change Ubuntu logo
[Original logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2PBa.png)

I replaced the `ubuntu_logo.png` with another custom .png file in

```
/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo
```

but when it restarted, it shows this image instead of the custom .png file

[Wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTdnu.png)

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Is your .png the same format as the default one (same size, transparency, ...) ? And was it already in the png format or did you just change the file extension ?

Comment: I edited from original file .png it has the same resolution

Answer (score 0):

Once you're sure your new image is in the right format, then make sure your image (and any other configuration) is **updated in the initial RAM disk**.

The startup/shutdown system called Plymouth reads theme information straight from the regular disk filesystem on shutdown, so changing a PNG file is all you need to do for that. For startup, though, Plymouth runs before the real disk is available. Instead, it reads files from a special area called the "initial RAM disk".

To update the existing RAM disk with your new settings, run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```